# for loop with two indices in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, for-loop, nested-for-loop

It's possible to use for loop with double indices in Java, e.g:

```java
for (int j = 0, k = myArray.length - 1; j < myArray.length; j++, k--)
```

To iterate myArray elements from the first element using j and from the last element using k simultaneously without using inner loop. How can we do this in Kotlin without using inner loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need an inner loop. Just create an additional variable inside for loop.

```kotlin
for(j in myArray.indices) {
    val k = myArray.size - 1 - j
    // Use j and k here
}
```

Or alternatively,

```kotlin
var k = myArray.size - 1
for(j in myArray.indices) {
    // Use j and k here
    k--
}
```

Comment: Option 1 is really innovative.

Answer (score 2):

**Kotlin doesn't provide a way to permit what you attempt to do.**

Because I imagine your case is purely for exemple, I purpose you two solutions:

### 1. The good old way

The most optimized for the exemple you give.

```
for (i in a.indices) {
    val j = a.size - 1 - i
    println("($i, $j)")
}
```

> (0, 3)(1, 2)(2, 1)(3, 0)

[See code snippet on play.kotlinlang.org](https://pl.kotl.in/BLqOOsc4m)

### 2. The .zip() way

Can be usefull on some contexts, the zip method combine two lists of the same size on one list of Tuples which can be used after directly.

```
val indices = a.indices;
for (i in indices.zip(indices.reversed())) {
    println(i)
}
```

> (0, 3)(1, 2)(2, 1)(3, 0)

[See code snippet on play.kotlinlang.org](https://pl.kotl.in/gFFeB9Z-N)

Answer (score 0):

`generateSequence()` is powerful alternative for complex loops. Not so fast as pure for/while loop but very flexible and easy.

```kotlin
generateSequence(
    0 to myArray.size - 1 // initial values
) {
    it.first + 1 to it.second - 1 // new values after each iteration
}.takeWhile {
    it.first < myArray.size // limit
}.forEach { (j, k) ->
    println("$j $k")
}
```

And yes, it's good idea to not iterate second variable but calculate it from first (if applicable), as suggested in other answers.